# How to use unit test with vuex-loading

Tags: unit-testing, vue-test-utils

I would like to write a unit test with the async action that use vuetify, vuex, vuex-loading such as:
*File Navigation.vue:*

```
<template>
  <div class="multipane__aside">
    <v-btn
      :disabled="$loading.isLoading('call ajax')" 
      @click="fetchResults"
      color="primary" 
    >
      <v-loading loader='call ajax'>
        <template slot='spinner'>Loading...</template>
      </v-loading>
      Call ajax
    </v-btn>
    <div v-if="$loading.isLoading('call ajax')">call ajax...</div>
    <ul v-if="items.length">
      <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <strong>{{ item.title }}</strong> <br>
        {{ item.body }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'RecipeNavigation',
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['items'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['getAsync']),
    fetchResults () {
      this.getAsync()
    },
    onClose () {
      this.$emit('close', this.$el)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

*File Navigation.spec.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import vueLoading from 'vuex-loading'
import { shallow, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Navigation from '@/components/Navigation'
import { stat } from 'fs';

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(vueLoading)

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

describe('Navigation', () => {
  let store
  let actions
  let state

  beforeEach(() => {
    state = { 
      items: []
    }

    actions = {
      getAsync: jest.fn()
    }

    store = new Vuex.Store({
      state,
      actions
    })
  })

  it('dispatches an getAsync action', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(Navigation, {
      store,
      localVue
    })
    wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    expect(actions.getAsync).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

*The result of this test:*
 [Vue warn]: Error in config.errorHandler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoading' of undefined"

Please help me to pass this issue. Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: Just a hunch but... have you tried replacing the import with: `import VueLoading from 'vuex-loading'` and then doing `localVue.use(VueLoading)`?